# What would be the price of cheaper Glove of Storing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I would like to get a Glove of Storing but I cannot afford the current price.

> **Glove of Storing**
>
> Aura moderate transmutation; CL 6th; Slot hands; Price 10,000 gp; Weight —
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This device is a single leather glove. On command, one item held in the hand wearing the glove disappears. The item can weigh no more than 20 pounds and must be able to be held in one hand. While stored, the item has negligible weight. With a snap of the fingers wearing the glove, the item reappears. A glove can only store one item at a time. Storing or retrieving the item is a free action. The item is shrunk down so small within the palm of the glove that it cannot be seen. Spell durations are not suppressed, but continue to expire. If the glove’s effect is suppressed or dispelled, the stored item appears instantly. A glove of storing uses up the wearer’s entire hands slot. The wearer may not use another item (even another glove of storing) that also uses the hands slot.
>
> CONSTRUCTION REQUIREMENTS
>
> Craft Wondrous Item, shrink item; Cost 5,000 gp.

[source d20pfsrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/e-g/glove-of-storing/)

A less powerful glove would do the trick. For example, a glove with 3 charges per day would be enough.

I made a quick run with a rules but all I have got is `3 * 5 * 1800 (for command word) / 5 * 3` = 16200gp. This is even higher than the original price!

I was hoping for a price around 4 to 5k. How can I have cheaper price?

Edit: I am aware of the [Glove of Storing](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/3e_SRD:Glove_of_Storing) and the [Glove of Master Strategist](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/items.php?ID=3624) from D&D 3.0, but I cant imagine a DM allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Glove of storing* is not a command-word item of *shrink item*, so your \$3\times 5\times 1800\text{ gp}\$ is entirely off-base. By the guidelines here, you would just divide by 5/3, that is, multiply by 3/5 for 6000 gp.

That said, 3 uses of the *glove of storing* seems, well actually it seems ambiguous. Is that three store/retrieve cycles, or three stores or retrieves total? The later does not seem very useful, particularly since it is asymmetrical. You might want to clarify that with the GM.

Also note that the *glove of storing* comes straight from D&D 3.5e, where it received a massive price hike over 3e. The general consensus was that this price hike was a mistake, and the *glove of the master strategist*, a 3e upgrade to the *glove of storing* that was price based on the 3e price and therefore actually cheaper than the 3.5e (or Pathfinder) *glove of storing*, was commonly suggested and used. You might ask your GM about using the 3e price, or using the *glove of the master strategist*. You say you can’t imagine a GM allowing them, but many do.

Comment: I thought about three cycles. but I see the why it could be ambiguous. If using GoMS is not as broken as I think it coulde be, I will ask for it!

Comment: My DM say ok no problem. Well, GoMS  here we go \o/